do i need to remove contact spray adhesive from a hardboard floor before using a one part self levelling compound?
Long story short, I used contact spray adhesive on some cheap adhesive tiles that wouldn't stick properly on a hardboard floor, as a quick fix in our new build ensuite.
Toilet cistern recently leaked and obviously needed to be removed and said tiles taken up to air out the water damage that had lifted them.
all is dried out and was caught in time to prevent any serious water damage. its been airing out for about 4 weeks but the contact adhesive is still tacky.
is it safe to apply a one part self levelling compound straight over the tacky adhesive?
if yes, what's the worst that could happen?
if no, what would be the best way to remove it without damaging the hardboard?

The manufacturer will tell you that the floor must be clean and free from debris.  This debris is stuff that is crumbly and loose on the floor.
If the glue is stuck and flat and the leveling pour will cover it all you are ok.
What is the worst that can happen?   If the glue isn't hard and doesn't harden and it stays soft under the leveling compound, the weight of walking will make things crumble. But that is an extreme scenario.

The issue may come when there's debris bits that can't be removed because they gets stuck to the adhesive!
